# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 56,Token in error = ) ]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been receiving the following message when I try my codes.

'There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 56,Token in error = )] '

Does anybody here knows what's causing it?

This is my code:

```
var db=Database.Open("databaseName");
var username=WebSecurity.CurrentUserName.ToString();
var newFileName="";
WebImage img=null;


img = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +Path.GetFileName(img.FileName);
db.Execute("UPDATE Customer SET custBackground=@0 WHERE custUser=@1)", newFileName, username);
```

img allows null to be returned, but when I am trying my codes I ensure that img is not null.

Really appreciate any help I can get from all of you! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it without the extra `)`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Where is the extra ) ?

Comment: There is only one `)` in your SQL query, at the end: `=@1)"`

Comment: @RowlandShaw OMG that's an embarrassing mistake. Thank you! Works now!